# Floating widget in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, floating

I am trying to implement floating widget in React Native (source: https://thunderwiring.wordpress.com/2018/04/01/creating-floating-chat-head-like-messenger-in-android/ )

My target is use React Native for render this widget.

When I am trying to run this floating widget in MainActivity `public class MainActivity extends ReactFragmentActivity` by this code `startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingCallingService.class));`, then I get error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
>   com.tc.background.FloatingCallingService@d6c8a7b with Intent {
>   cmp=com.tc/.background.FloatingCallingService }:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Error inflating class fragment

Here is my source code:

```
public class FloatingCallingService extends Service {
    private View floatingBubbleView;
    private WindowManager windowManager;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (startId == Service.START_STICKY) {
                handleStart();
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void handleStart() {


        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        floatingBubbleView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.floating_layout, null);


        int LAYOUT_FLAG;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        }

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 50;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.addView(floatingBubbleView, params);
```

floating_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/floating_bubble_root"
    >
    <!--Close button-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
    <fragment android:name="com.tc.background.FloatingFragment"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

FloatingFragment.java:

```
public class FloatingFragment extends ReactFragment {

    @Override
    public String getMainComponentName() {
        return "Calling";
    }
}
```

ReactFragment.java:

```
public abstract class ReactFragment extends Fragment {
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    // This method returns the name of our top-level component to show
    public abstract String getMainComponentName();

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(context);
        mReactInstanceManager =
                ((MainApplication) getActivity().getApplication())
                        .getReactNativeHost()
                        .getReactInstanceManager();

    }

    @Override
    public ReactRootView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return mReactRootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(
                mReactInstanceManager,
                getMainComponentName(),
                null
        );
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
            android:name=".background.FloatingCallingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you solved the Topic and got your app to work this way?

Comment: No, I did not. I moved my app from React Native to pure Android.